# How to build up anonymous array of parameters

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I have a query

```
string sQuery = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM vwweb_Orders WHERE CustFID = ?", columns);
```

that gets executed here

```
var result = await conn.QueryAsync<Order>(sQuery, new { ID = Custid });
```

But say that I'm searching based on parameters chosen by the user. I can build up the where clause, but how do I build up the anonymous array?

```
new { ID = Custid }
```

I want something like

```
var params = new {};
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username)) {
   params += {username}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to have params like an anonymous type, you can use an `ExpandoObject`:-

```
dynamic params = new ExpandoObject();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username)) {
    params.Username = username;
}
```

Or if you want an array (and you don't know the length ahead of time), use a `List<string>`:-

```
var paramlist = new List<string>();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username)) {
    paramlist.Add("username");
}

var params = paramlist.ToArray();
```

However, if you are constructing the `WHERE` clause, you will always have a fixed number of parameters in your SQL statement anyway (or you'll have to construct it dynamically too).

One other method you can use when dynamically building a query for filtering is this:-

```
SELECT *
FROM vwweb_Orders
WHERE 1=1
AND (@custid IS NULL OR CustFID = @custid)
AND (@xyz IS NULL OR XYZ = @xyz)
-- etc
```

Then supply all the parameters to your `QueryAsync` call, and if any are null, they'll be skipped in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I was planning on constructing the where clause on the fly, as I said in the question. I hadn't considered doing the conditional in the query itself. I'll keep that in mind. Unfortunately, I feel like that makes it a little less readable, so I'll go with your list to array approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write your query to check for null/empty/non-zero values first otherwise evaluate the real values as follows:

```
public async Task<List<Order>> Execute(OrderQuery query)
{

    var sql = $@"SELECT
                    ...
                FROM vwweb_Orders
                WHERE @{nameof(query.CustomerId)} <= 0 OR customer_id = @{nameof(query.CustomerId)}
                    AND ISNULL(@{nameof(query.CustomerName)}, '') = '' OR customer_name = @{nameof(query.CustomerName)}";

    return await conn.QueryAsync<Order>(sql, new { query.CustomerId, query.CustomerName});

}

public class OrderQuery
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
}
```